# what is difference between asp .net and asp .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I know that Asp .Net core is one framework but what is difference between Asp .Net and Asp .Net Core ? What are differences between their functionalities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The CORE frameworks which includes ASP.net CORE is basically just a framework which allows it to be hosted on multiple operating systems such as Windows, MAC and Linux.

Essentially the same functionality as regular ASP.NET but with multi platform support.

However since it is new there are some new features.
Some are detailed here 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/14-new-things-about-Asp-Net-5/

Comment: Also worth noting that if you are doing something like building a reusable class library you can do so in “net standard” and it will be compatible with both.